# Codeigniter: How to redirect user to read the topic they just post after click submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form for user to write article. I want after user click submit the system will redirect user to read their new post(usually I just show message saying success).

Controller

```
 if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
            //after everything ok insert new topic to database
            $this->load->model('topic_model');
            if($this->topic_model->insert_topic()==TRUE)
            {

              echo 'true';
            }
        } else {
            echo validation_errors();
        }
```

Ajax

```
 success: function (data) {
                if (data === 'true')
                {
                    $('#myerror1').html('Success');
                }
                else
                {
                    $('#myerror1').html(data);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

why you are sending status to client as your topic get inserted you have to redirect it from current controller to another controller is a common controller for viewing your topic get that topic from url and show that topic in that common controller

```
if($this->topic_model->insert_topic()==TRUE){
     redirect("{topic_controller_name}/{topic name}");
}
```

and in common controller

```
public {topic controller name} extends CI_Controller{
     public function index($topic){
         $data = $this->topic _model->get_topic($topic);
        // sens this to view and show topic.
    }
}
```